# Dictionary insertion order

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, while-loop

I wanted to know why the output of this code doesn't follow the things list. When output, the code is `{0: 0, 2.0: 0.5, 4: 1, 5: 1}` instead of `{4: 1, 5: 1, 2.0: 0.5, 0: 0}`. Thanks for help.

```
ctr = 0
rtc = 1
things = [4,5,2.0,0]
d = {}

#block 1
    while ctr < len(things):
    d[things[ctr]] = things[ctr] / 4 
    ctr += 1
print d
```

Comment: I wonder why do you care about their order in first place?, while you can just use _keys_ to get whatever you want.

Comment: The dictionary in python is implemented as a hash table, so it tends to store the keys and thereby values in accordance with their hash values in that table.That's why the order is not maintained according to your input sequence.

Answer (score 0):

With a standard Python dictionary, there is no guarantee that elements will remain in the order they were inserted.. You should use an

> OrderedDict

from the **collections** package if you want that behavior .

For Python 2.7, see the official documentation for the collections OrderedDict  at

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Your example, modified:

```
import collections

ctr = 0
rtc = 1
things = [4,5,2.0,0]
d = collections.OrderedDict()


while ctr < len(things):
    d[things[ctr]] = things[ctr] / 4 
    ctr += 1
print d
```

Output:

OrderedDict([(4, 1), (5, 1), (2.0, 0.5), (0, 0)])

Accessing elements by key is similar to an ordinary dict:

```
print d[4]
print d[2.0]
```

gives 1 and 0.5 respectively.

Comment: Every time the code is run, it outputs the same way.

Comment: The order of entry in the standard dict is determined by the underlying hashing algorithm. That does not mean it's random.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out python dictionaries do not guarantee that the items can be accessed in the same order as the order of insertion. This is because python list and dictionary are different data structures each has its own way of retrieving values. If you're interested in this check out this amazing [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68) to understand how dictionary items are stored and retrieved and why order is not preserved.

That being said if you simply want to print or access the items of the dictionary based on items in `things` there are several options as below apart from `Ordereddict` already mentioned.

List comprehension

```
>>> print [(key, d[key]) for key in things]                                                                                                          
[(4, 1), (5, 1), (2.0, 0.5), (0, 0)]
>>> print "{ %s }" % ", ".join(["%s : %s" % (key, d[key]) for key in d])
{ 0 : 0, 2.0 : 0.5, 4 : 1, 5 : 1 }
```

You can also sort the dictionary based on the `things` list

```
>>> print sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: things.index(x[0]))
[(4, 1), (5, 1), (2.0, 0.5), (0, 0)]
```